# How do I remove a model but keep the database table on Django

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I want to remove the class declaration of the model but want to keep the records and the table on the database. How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the model then? You can simply keep the model, but no longer do anything with it.

Comment: I want to just remove because it's a useless declaration of a class that is not going to be used anywhere

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Stop Django managing your model by setting the `Meta` class attribute `managed` to `False` (default is `True`) like in the following:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    ....

    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

Then run `python manage.py makemigrations`, which should create a migration telling you something like

```
- Change Meta options on something
```

Run that migration by `python manage.py migrate`, which will stop Django from managing that model and then delete it from your code base. The migration will look like:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('blah', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterModelOptions(
            name='something',
            options={'managed': False},
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: As for Django 2.2, after migrating to `managed = False`, when deleting the model, running `./manage makemigrations` still creates a `migrations.DeleteModel` migration automatically... what am I missing?

Comment: Hi Tomyo! I ran into the same issue and tested it locally to see what happens. Its true that it creates a DeleteModel migration, but when running it I noticed that the table was retained.

Answer (score -1):

If the class it not going to be used anywhere but you want to keep the data:

- Do a dump of that data and create a new database to store the dump data.
- Delete the model.
- Make a migration deleting the model.

If you delete the model in the code I think that always you execute a `manage makemigrations` it will create a migration to delete the table.

Comment: This "If you delete the model in the code I think that always you execute a manage makemigrations it will create a migration to delete the table." is not a true statement

Comment: @n8sty I tried it, I've deleted the class from models and then execute `make migrations` and it has created a migration for deleting the table.

Comment: Yep - see my answer which explains why. In short, you can remove a model from being managed by Django, which should allow you to delete it without the creation of a migration

Comment: ohh yeah I forgot the part where you says `and then delete it from your code base` ;)